# Convert SQL to Laravel ORM RELATONS

Tags: php, sql, laravel

It is working but I should do with Relaion

```
SELECT * FROM product JOIN ware_houses ON  product.id=ware_houses.product_id WHERE ware_houses.variant_id=1;
```

Like this...

```
Product::whereHas('ware_houses')->where('ware_houses.product_id',1)->get();
```

But it is not working because `whereHas` returns a collection, What I can do ??? Please give advice.

Comment: add "->first()" just before the 'get()' method

Comment: You only need one of them, not both.

Comment: it is not just one , it will be dynamic , I just put for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working thank you !!!

```
 $products=Product::whereHas('wareHouse',function(Builder $query) use ($id){
         $query->where('ware_houses.variant_id',$id);
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `whereHas()` to actually filter:

```php
Product::whereHas('ware_houses', function($q) {
    $q->where('ware_houses.product_id',1);
})->get();
```